# Why is this momentjs date incorrect?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Here is my code:

```
var moment = require("moment"); 

var day = 31;
var month = 12;
var year = 2016;
moment().date(day).month(month - 1).year(year)
```

The date that is returned is `Sat Dec 03 2016 16:23:43 GMT-0700 (MST)`.

Why is the date being converted to `03` instead of `31`?

Comment: " if you chain multiple actions to construct a date, you should start from a year, then a month, then a day etc. Otherwise you may get unexpected results" https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: If you make a date for 31 December and subtract a month, what should the date be? There is no 31 November.

Comment: @RobG `moment().year(2016).month(11).date(31).month(10)` returns November 30, 2016. It is handled well.

Comment: @JoeFrambach—yes, but what *should* it be?

Comment: Excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is processed in multiple steps: `moment().date(day).month(month - 1).year(year)`

First: `moment().date(31)`

It is currently February 7th, 2017. We are changing it to "February 31st, 2017", which wraps around to March 3rd since February has only 28 days.

Then it changes the month to 12, and the year to 2016.

Flip the steps around. Do the year first, then month, then date.